# Exporting form from one ms access 2013 database to another loses button functionality

Tags: vba, ms-access

I exported a form from one database to another. The table names and queries are the exact same, so my combo box which lets me select a table still works properly and shows all the tables. I had a button which lets me select a folder location by opening windows explorer. This worked on my original db, but in the new one I get this error:

> The expression On Click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Variable not defined.
>
> *The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
>
> *There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.

When I clicked OK however it did not bring me to a line in the VBA code that caused the problem. I am thinking that it's not the code, but somewhere I had to do some configuring but I don't know for sure. This happens for all my buttons. I have an event for each button which is an on click event. I went to the vba editor and checked out if I needed to add in the code but it was already there.

In the properties sheet of my form, all the events are set up, names of each component are the same so I don't see what could be the problem. How do I get the functionality back without completely redesigning my form?

**Edit:** I don't know much about privacy with respect to VBA coding, but could it have something to do with the fact that all of my button_Click() functions are public in both databases? I feel like it wouldn't but I thought it was worth asking.

**Edit 2:** Here is the code for the button that opens up windows explorer:

```
Public Sub pathButton1_Click()

    Dim strPath As String
    With Me
        strPath = Left(.pathLabel1.Caption, InStrRev(.pathLabel1.Caption, "/"))
        strPath = FSBrowse(strStart:=strPath, _
                           lngType:=msoFileDialogFolderPicker, _
                           strPattern:="MS Access Databases,*.ACCDB; *.MDB~" & _
                                       "All Files,*.*")
        If strPath > "" Then .pathLabel1.Caption = strPath
    End With

End Sub

Public Function FSBrowse(Optional strStart As String = "", _
                         Optional lngType As MsoFileDialogType = _
                             msoFileDialogFolderPicker, _
                         Optional strPattern As String = "All Files,*.*" _
                         ) As String
    Dim varEntry As Variant

    FSBrowse = ""
    With Application.FileDialog(DialogType:=lngType)
        'Set the title to match the type used from the list
        .Title = "Browse for "
        Select Case lngType
        Case msoFileDialogOpen
            .Title = .Title & "File to open"
        Case msoFileDialogSaveAs
            .Title = .Title & "File to SaveAs"
        Case msoFileDialogFilePicker
            .Title = .Title & "File"
        Case msoFileDialogFolderPicker
            .Title = .Title & "Folder"
        End Select
        If lngType <> msoFileDialogFolderPicker Then
            Call .Filters.Clear
            For Each varEntry In Split(strPattern, "~")
                Call .Filters.Add(Description:=Split(varEntry, ",")(0), _
                                  Extensions:=Split(varEntry, ",")(1))
            Next varEntry
        End If
        'Set some default settings
        .InitialFileName = strStart
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        'Only return a value from the FileDialog if not cancelled.
        If .Show Then FSBrowse = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Posting the vba code giving the error would help.

Comment: @ChristopherD. I edited my post. That's for one of the buttons

Comment: Try putting `Option Explicit` at the top of each function and running the code. It should at least get more specific about which variable isn't being defined.

Comment: I had that at the top of my module before, but I added it in above every function but still got the same error message

Comment: Also @ChristopherD. when it gives me that error and I click OK, it doesn't bring me to the vba editor with any line selected. I just figured it was referring to one of my OnClick() functions but it was very vague as to what the actual problem was